# Backbone model is undefined

Tags: javascript, svg, backbone.js

I have a collection of operators and the operator view is supposed to draw the operator container on an svg. But I get the `TypeError:this.model is undefined` for the last line. Why am I getting this error?

```
  var Operators = new DataMapper.Collections.Operators(); //Operators is a collection defined previously 
  var concatModel = new DataMapper.Models.Operator({title: "Concat", id: "concat" + new Date().getTime(), inputCount: 2, outputCount: 1});
  var concatView = new DataMapper.Views.OperatorView({model: concatModel});
  Operators.add([concatModel]);
```

[image]

UPDATE: The code expanded - I'm using backbone_1.3.3

```
        DataMapper.Collections.Operators = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: DataMapper.Models.Operator
        });
        DataMapper.Views.OperatorPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#op-panel",
            events: {
                "click #concat-op-btn": "addConcatOp"
            },
            addConcatOp: function () {
                var concatModel = new DataMapper.Models.Operator({title: "Concat", id: "concat" + new Date().getTime(), inputCount: 2, outputCount: 1});
                var concatView = new DataMapper.Views.OperatorView({model: concatModel});
                //console.log(concatModel);
                DataMapper.Operators.add([concatModel]); //where error occurs
            }
        });

        DataMapper.Views.CanvasView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#canvas",
            params: {
                inputStartX: 40,
                inputStartY: 40,
                outputStartX: 800,
                outputStartY: 40,
                elementWidth: 170,
                elementHeight: 20
            },
            initialize: function () {
                DataMapper.Operators = new DataMapper.Collections.Operators(); //initialize a collection
                new DataMapper.Views.LoadFileView();
                new DataMapper.Views.OperatorPanelView();
            }
        });
  new DataMapper.Views.CanvasView();
```

Comment: add the block of the code where you get this error

Comment: 1) can you add the Operators collection definition (code) ?

Comment: 2)what version of Backbone do you use?

Comment: @VladuIonut I'm using backbone_1.3.3